# Web Api Core hangs when start it on IIS Express in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I just updated Visual Studio to final version of 2017.
I'm working on a WebApi core project.

[image: VS2017-WebApi]

Whenever I start it with IIS Express, Google Chrome comes up and stay on loading in the following page without any responses

[image: VS2017-WebApi-Chrome]

What's wrong with it?
[The problem on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1968)

Comment: Try disabling javascript debugging in VS. For me that only caused issues so far.

Comment: I've done it, Unfortunately nothing change, just new tab open in existing google chrome window instead of opening new chrome window. It stay on page in loading mode without any responses

Comment: Does it work without IIS?

Comment: Yes, it works without IIS in `Web Api`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling `IISExpress` on WebApi Core:

**1.** Enabling the IISIntegration components:
Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration` package.

**2.** Edit `Program.cs` in root of project:

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration() // Add this line
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)! Cheer!

Comment: @Smilefounder, I have the same issue and I tried the mentioned solution, but it didn't work ... any ideas?

Comment: @AhmedNegm: This solution has been posted from March 2017 and it is related to .net core version 1. I think your latest issue facing an issue with dotnet core version 2. Could you explain more detail on your issue?

Comment: I have a project uses .net core 1.1 .. and when i installed new visual studio with .net core 2, i got that issue. Just when start debugging, the browser opens then closes and stopped debugging. Although if i started a new project it opens normally with no issues.

Comment: @AhmedNegm: I think it is because of the new way to switch between v1 and v2 once you installed the v2. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json for more detail. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by download the latest Visual Studio 2017 installer again then install with modify mode. They have some update just today.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTY5s.png)
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdfkf.png)

Comment: I didn't see somethong about the problem in Visual Studio release note!

Comment: I updated to last version, nothing changed. I have the problem again

Comment: Please see my new answer as below and let me know if it work for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i had to disable javascript debugging to get it to work. under options>debugging> uncheck Enable javascript for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I came across this error in VS 2019: netcoreapp3.1

The correct way to build the web host is adding to the DefaultBuilder

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();
```

But if you want to do this manually you must UseIIS() in addition to UseIISIntegration()

```
      return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(YourAppConfigurationMethod)
            .UseIIS()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Comment: This was the solution for me!